# Rich Faces Equivalent Component of List BOX

Tags: richfaces

I have the following functionality . I have two list boxes , depending on the value selected in the first list box , the values in the second list box needs to be populated . I need to implement this functionality in rich faces . I am new to rich faces and my rich faces version is 3.3.3. I went through all the components in rich faces but did not find anything related to list box . Can any body suggest on this ?

Thanks
Mahi

Answer (score 1):

try to use the default JSF list component.

If I'm not mistaken, it's h:selectOneMenu component.

Look at this: http://exadel.com/web/portal/jsftags-guide

Answer (score 0):

A little late here. [RichFaces 4](http://richfaces.jboss.org/) now comes with a pick list control that let you do what you stated in the question, check out the [demo](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList&skin=blueSky)